# storm.kafka.UpdateOffsetException - Issue with Opaque Trident Kafka Spout

Tags: clojure, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm using trident topology with OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout.

Code snippet of TridentKafkaConfig i’m using :-

```
OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout kafkaSpout = null;
TridentKafkaConfig spoutConfig = new TridentKafkaConfig(new ZkHosts("xxx.x.x.9:2181,xxx.x.x.1:2181,xxx.x.x.2:2181"), "topic_name");
spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
spoutConfig.fetchSizeBytes = 147483600;
kafkaSpout = new OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
```

I get this runtime exception from one of the workers :-

> java.lang.RuntimeException: storm.kafka.UpdateOffsetException at
>   backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:135)
>   at
>   backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:106)
>   at
>   backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80)
>   at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn_5694$fn5707$fn5758.invoke(executor.clj:819)
>   at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn545.invoke(util.clj:479) at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   storm.kafka.UpdateOffsetException at
>   storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.fetchMessages(KafkaUtils.java:186) at
>   storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.fetchMessages(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:132)
>   at
>   storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.doEmitNewPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:113)
>   at
>   storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.failFastEmitNewPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:72)
>   at
>   storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.emitNewPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:79)
>   at
>   storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.access$000(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:46)
>   at
>   storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter$1.emitPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:204)
>   at
>   storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter$1.emitPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:194)
>   at
>   storm.trident.spout.OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor$Emitter.emitBatch(OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor.java:127)
>   at
>   storm.trident.spout.TridentSpoutExecutor.execute(TridentSpoutExecutor.java:82)
>   at
>   storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.execute(TridentBoltExecutor.java:370)
>   at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn5694$tuple_action_fn5696.invoke(executor.clj:690)
>   at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn5615.invoke(executor.clj:436)
>   at
>   backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify_5189.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58)
>   at
>   backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:127)
>   ... 6 more

As per some posts, I have tried setting spoutConfig :-
spoutConfig.maxOffsetBehind = Long.MAX_VALUE;
spoutConfig.startOffsetTime = kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime();
My Kafka retention time is default - 128 Hours i.e. 7 Days and kafka producer is sending 6800 messages/second to Storm/Trident topology. I have gone through most of the posts, but none of them seem to solve this issue. What's the best way to handle this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still dont know what caused this issue. But basically we did not shut down storm, zookeeper and kafka properly. This resulted in storm topologies failing, we had to tear down the entire cluster and re-build it again. Updating to storm 0.10.0 helped fixing some of the other issues.